# polling Issue when context.sendResponse is used in gupshup

Tags: javascript, gupshup

I am polling a url for notifications in gupshup, and after i got a notification,i am doing context.sendResponse to display it on bot.But after context.sendResponse, further notifications are listened and i can see those notifications in logs but they are not displayed into bot eventhough context.sendResponse is provided.How can we resolve this or how we can do polling effectively using gupshup

```
    function pollForNotifications(context, XMLHttpRequest, to_json) {
        timer = setInterval(function() {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState === 4) {
                    to_json(this.responseText, function(error, data) {
                        var json = data.rss.channel.item;
                        if (lastRecievedData == null) {
                            //some logic 
                            context.sendResponse(info); 
                        } else {
                            //some logic 
                            context.sendResponse(info);
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
            xhr.open("GET", "rally1.rallydev.com/slm/rss/notifications/All.rss");
            xhr.send();
        }, 5000);
    }
```

I am polling rally for notifications and after i get a response i am displaying it on bot. When a bot is started, it listens to notifications and notifications are displayed on bot. Further notifications are recieved and i can check those recieved notifications in log and log says response has been sent to bot and still bot doesnt displays any response

Comment: Maybe you could add some code to show your problem? [ask]

Comment: Instead of adding the information into the comments, you should better editing the question so readers better understand the problem. Regards